# Track user activity using google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics).

We would like the analysis of our data data to focus on specific brand promotion, in my application I have the data from twitter, facebook and instagram. I would like to track user activity and collect data on click event such as

- Title of the post
- date of the post
- channel(twitter,facebook,instagram)
- etc.

I want to use an `application unique user id` and analyze the data based on  a specific userid.

I have read custom Variables in Google Analytics, but I am not sure about how much analytics will help me to tracked above information.

Answer (score 3):

From the Google Analytics [Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html):

> 7. Privacy.
>
> You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service
>   to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an
>   individual (such as a name, email address or billing information), or
>   other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by
>   Google. You will have and abide by an appropriate Privacy Policy and
>   will comply with all applicable laws, policies, and regulations
>   relating to the collection of information from Visitors.

That being said if your website has a Userid that can not be used to directly map back to a user. You could place that user id into a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).

You need only [configure](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#configuration) it in your Google analytics account then add a tracking code like this to your site

> ga('set', 'dimension1', 'XXXXXXXX');

Then you will be able to use user id as a secondary dimension in most of the Reports on the website.