# Tracking individual user activity using Google Analytics and then showing suggestions

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say I have a restaurant-review website where users can post reviews about the restaurants they visit.Can I use google analytics to track the information that each user searches/accesses on my website and then show him information related to it? Also, I'd like to know if someone visits my website and browses through some reviews without logging-in and then logs in, can I track the review pages he browsed before and then show them to him as his recent views when he is logged-in using GA? If not, I'd like to know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can track an anonymous user activity and then map them when the user loges in. To do that in the application level you need to have an activity table with the application and track the user activity. Once the user loges in you just need to update the identifier of the activity table with the user Id.
Details can be fond on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679251/tracking-anonymous-user-activity).

Here is how to do it with [Google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838944/track-user-activity-using-google-analytics): 
You might need to setup the analytics properly. Not sure about mapping the two user (anonymous and post login) data.